# Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "image"

Tags: json, wordpress, api, rest

I've an error when i execute the API JSON :
This is my code :

```
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post);
        if (!image) {
            $image = "";
        }
```

And the error :

Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "image" in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\wp-content\themes\twentytwenty\functions.php:873

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in this line.

```
if (!image) {
```

.. it should be.

```
if (!$image) {
```

It is a weird logic though because it says that when the $image is undefined or empty, empty it or assign a blank string literal to it.